# Delhi to Kathmandu by land

Tags: india, nepal

I expect to be sent to Delhi on business for a month, probably August.  I have requested a week of leave in the middle of the visit.  A week of leave would allow 9 days as I could use the two adjacent weekends.  One plan that I am considering for this leave is a trip to Nepal.  My priority will be an interesting trip rather than a quick one.  Comfort is not a high priority. So, I am considering going by land.

I have spent a lot time in India but it was very long ago.  I backpacked around for over 6 months.  I am well used to low budget travel there. I have been more recently but not Delhi and just typical business travel with no side trips.

However, I am a lot older and more wealthy than in my backpacking days.  I still want to prioritise interest over comfort, hence land, but maybe not quite as tough as in backpacking days.

What are my options?  I am aware that a return trip by land in 9 days may leave me little time in Nepal.  That may be acceptable if the journey itself is interesting.  At least, I want to consider this option before the obvious one of flying.

Comment: Your question is drawing close votes as "too broad". With only a week, I'd think that wouldn't leave you much time in Nepal itself.

Comment: I'm asking how to travel between two specific cities by land.  It does not seem very broad to me.  How could I make it more specific?

Comment: Asking for opinions about what's 'best', and itineraries are also off topic. Have you contacted specialist travel agents?

Comment: I have rephrased my question to just ask for options i.e. what is possible without requesting any value judgement on best.  I had hoped that some had made this trip or something similar.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert That's useful.  I'm surprised that I failed to find it my search.  Usually, a close match like that shows up when you enter the title.